# SALV event at grid initialization?

Tags: abap, alv

I am creating a SALV grid in a simplistic manner avoiding screens and containers:

```
TRY.
    cl_salv_table=>factory(
      IMPORTING
        r_salv_table = lo_alv
      CHANGING
        t_table      = itab ).
  CATCH cx_salv_msg INTO exc.
ENDTRY.
...
lo_alv->set_screen_status( pfstatus = 'SALV_STATUS'
                           report = sy-repid
                           set_functions = lo_alv->c_functions_all ).
...
lo_alv->display( ).
```

I want to show the standard `MESSAGE` only **once** upon grid display, making it showed in the bottom status bar.

I tried PAGE events, but they are not fired on start, only after pressing standard toolbar button

```
  SET HANDLER cl_event_handler=>on_top_of_page FOR lo_events.
  SET HANDLER cl_event_handler=>on_end_of_page FOR lo_events.
```

I also tried putting `MESSAGE` after the `display( )` method, but this way it is showed after I exit the grid with back button, and this is not what I want, I want it showed exactly under the grid at the moment of first load.

Is there an event that is triggered on grid initialization or after rendering/loading data?

If not, is there any workaround to make this work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the message *before* calling `lo_alv->display( )`. This complete program seems to behave the way you want. The status message "Hello World" appears below the ALV grid with the data:

```
REPORT Z_TEST_SALV_MESSAGE.

SELECT * FROM sflight INTO TABLE @DATA(gt_sflight).

cl_salv_table=>factory(
  IMPORTING
    r_salv_table = DATA(lo_alv)
  CHANGING
    t_table      = gt_sflight ).

MESSAGE 'Hello World' TYPE 'S'.
lo_alv->display( ).
```